# Is mongoose schema necessary when you only need to extract data?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

This might be a dumb question but is it necessary to define a mongoose schema when I only need to extract information from Mongodb and not actually inserting or updating the database? From what I understand, the schema is to help structure information for when it is inserted into the database.

I am currently using NodeJS to create web application that uses mongoose to extract information from the database and simply displaying it out.

Comment: I'm not totally sure, but I think you would need to define a schema for the queried data to align with. You could try it though. If you're not using schemas you may not need to use Mongoose at all. It can do some nice things, but in my opinion the Mongo node.js driver has come a long way and is probably all you need at this point.

Comment: Yeap thanks! It didn't work when I tried the method JohnnyHK proposed. I still had to define a schema for me to display the information. :)